# Issues with Python-Django and PyQt4

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-scraping, pyqt4

**FIXED** This issue has been fixed by moving QApplication out of main().

Hi I'm trying to implement a web service that executes the JavaScript code of a given URL and gives back the final HTML. I'm using PyQt4 for JS processing and Django 1.4 web framework.
The problem is: the script always works in the command invite but when I integrate it to Django it works only the first time, after running the Django local server, then during the following executions it warns:

```
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread
QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

and I got wrong results.
The problem is that I'm not using any thread...
Here is the script I'm using on Django (urlconf leads to this main fonction with the url given):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from time import time, sleep

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

def wait(app, secs=1):
    deadline = time() + secs
    while time() < deadline:
        sleep(0)
        app.processEvents()

def main(url):
 #   app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    web = QWebView()
    web.load(QUrl(url))

    wait(app, 15)

    return web.page().mainFrame().toHtml().toUtf8()
```

Have you seen this before or tried to do something similar? Please help me with any information thank you

P.S. This is my first post here I hope everything is clear :)

**EDIT** The warnings are gone thanks to Rostyslav but I still have the sale issue.

Comment: I had the same annoying problem trying to generate maps whith QGIS server on django. Creating the QApplication in the views.py of my django project oustide the main() instead of creating it in the external python package that generates the map with QGIS made it work. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Cheers! I hope everything works fine for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually **you use threads**.

Django developments server uses threading by default. You can pass optional `--nothreading` parameter to `runserver` command which is intended to disable using threads by server:

```
python ./manage.py runserver --nothreading ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer I didn't knew that.
Now the warnings are gone but still have the same problem: 1st execution everything goes well (fully rendered html), next executions partial html and no javascript processing.
(In the shell the script always works)

Comment: The way I can point out for now is to check if any caching is performed on server.

Comment: I don't think it's a caching problem because I'm not using the same url twice, and no matter which url I use first, the response is right only the first time after (re)starting the django server. I think it's a PyQt problem and I have no clue. Anyway thank you